# What is the equivalent of "nice" for the GPU on *nix machines?

Tags: linux, unix, performance, gpu

If I have two GPU-intensive processes running, is there a way to "prefer" the load from one over the other, as "nice" does in the *nix kernel scheduler?

Comment: Would this be better on http://unix.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have luck using cgroups ([Linux documentation](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/devices.txt), [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups)).

It's mostly used for linux containers and such but you can allow or deny the usage of devices to processes of your choice.

This Gentoo [forum thread](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-910210-start-0.html) has some samples of how to restrict GPU usage (by denying /dev/nvidia0 to certain processes for example)